# Do something when pushed into an array, observable

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs, observable

I have an array x and an Observable from x(arrObs). There is a button and when user clicks on button, a random number is pushed into the array. I want the value to  be printed from the array whenever a value is pushed into it.

*http://jsbin.com/sovuyipuju/edit?js,console,output*

```
var x = [1,2,3,4];
var clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.querySelector('#button1'),'click');
clicks
  .map(function(y){return Math.floor(Math.random()*50)})
  .subscribe(function(z){  x.push(z);});

arrObs = Rx.Observable.from(x);
arrObs
  .map(function(x){  return x*2;})
  .subscribe(function(value){console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Whenever the button is clicked, a random value is pushed into the array. I want the array observable's subscribe to run on click

Comment: So, are you asking us to write that code for you? Or have you written it and are having difficulty with it? Please ask a question.

Comment: I have written the observable on array. As per my understanding it should log whenever a new item is pushed.Whenver button is clicked, value is pushed into array. But it is not logging

Answer (score 0):

Using pure js:

```
var arr=[];
arr.oldpush=arr.push.bind(arr);
arr.push=function(values...){
  values.forEach(console.log);
  this.oldpush(...values);
};
```

(I just think its not necessary to use a framework for that...)